# Problema com soma no vetor em C

Tags: c, array

Problema com soma dos vetores, estou tentando colocar a soma dos vetores diretamente no *loop*, mas ele não está fazendo a soma de todos e sim duplicando o ultimo vetor, testei o mesmo código em Portugol e funcionou perfeitamente, qual seria o problema em C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int apols[5],i,apolsTotal;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
    {
        printf("Digite a sua nota da apol %d\n",i);
        scanf("%d",&apols[i]);
        apolsTotal = apolsTotal + apols[i];
        //aqui esta o problema ele ta somando o ultimo valor com ele mesmo 
        //no caso apols[5] + apols[5]
    }

    /*apolsTotal = (apols[1] + apols[2] + apols[3] + apols[4] + apols[5])
    formula que funciona mas, não tao pratica*/
    printf("Total: %d\n",apolsTotal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Faltou inicializar o total com 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem dois problemas no código. O primeiro é que a variável de totalização não está sendo inicializada, então pega um número aleatório já existente na memória. Em C sempre tem que cuidar de tudo na memória. O segundo é que está indo de 1 à 5 quando na verdade o vetor começa pelo índice 0, sendo o último elemento (o quinto neste caso) o 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int apols[5] ,apolsTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Digite a sua nota da apol %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &apols[i]);
        apolsTotal += apols[i];
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n", apolsTotal);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yM0kmR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/owuehazf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SumArray.c).

Answer (score 2):

Em **C** a posição inicial de um vetor é 0 e a ultima posição é n-1, sendo n o tamanho setado para o vetor.

Portanto, o erro do seu código é tentar inserir na posição 5, e essa posição a linguagem não reconhece. E o outro erro é começar inserindo pela posição 1, e assim você está perdendo de inserir na posição 0. Eu fiz as alteração e agora ele funciona!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int apols[5],i,apolsTotal;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Digite a sua nota da apol %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &apols[i]);
        apolsTotal = apolsTotal + apols[i];
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n", apolsTotal);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O [vetor/array](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Vetores) em C inicia em `0`; então você precisa que o contador do seu *loop* também iniciem em *0*, já que ele é usado como índice do vetor:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    printf("Digite a sua nota da apol %d\n",i);
    scanf("%d",&apols[i]);
    apolsTotal = apolsTotal + apols[i];
}
```